# How to scrape list of tag attributes using beautiful soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a list of tag attributes in the `xml` file. But, I failed to scrape the list of tag attributes.

For instance, my data looks like

```
<sentences>    
<sentence id="1126814:0">
<Opinions>
    <Opinion target="Leon" category="RESTAURANT#GENERAL" polarity="positive" from="0" to="4"/>
    <Opinion target="Leon" category="AMBIENCE#GENERAL" polarity="positive" from="0" to="4"/>
    <Opinion target="specials" category="FOOD#QUALITY" polarity="positive" from="95" to="103"/>
    <Opinion target="atmosphere" category="AMBIENCE#GENERAL" polarity="positive" from="123" to="133"/>
    <Opinion target="French bistro fare" category="FOOD#QUALITY" polarity="positive" from="70" to="88"/>
    </Opinions>
</sentence>
</sentences>
```

I want to scrape each and every category within opinions tag.

```
category_list = ('1126814:0',[('RESTAURANT#GENERAL','positive')], [('AMBIENCE#GENERAL', 'positive')], [('FOOD#QUALITY', 'positive')], [('AMBIENCE#GENERAL', 'positive')])
```

I have tried the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open("new2.xml", "r") as file:
    url = file.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(url, "html.parser")
required0 = soup.find_all("sentences")

text1 = []
for i in required0:
    sent_id = []
    category = []
    for sentences in soup.find_all('sentence'):
        if sentences.has_attr('id'):
            sent_id.append(sentences['id'])
        text.append(sentences.get_text())
    for opinions in soup.find_all('opinion'):
        cat1 = []
        pola1 = []
        targ = []
        if opinions.has_attr('category'):
            cat1.append(opinions['category'])
        if opinions.has_attr('polarity'):
            pola1.append(opinions['polarity'])
        if opinions.has_attr('target'):
            targ.append(opinions['target'])
        cat_list = list(zip(cat1,pola1,targ))
        category.append(cat_list)
    catlist= list(zip(sent_id, category, category))
    text1.append(catlist)
```

I get the output as follows:

```
[[('1126814:0',
   [('RESTAURANT#GENERAL', 'positive', 'Leon')],
   [('RESTAURANT#GENERAL', 'positive', 'Leon')])]]
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please can you describe what your problem is? What do you need help with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution I used to obtain all the links. It's a modified version of your solution

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """<sentences>    
<sentence id="1126814:0">
<Opinions>
    <Opinion target="Leon" category="RESTAURANT#GENERAL" polarity="positive" from="0" to="4"/>
    <Opinion target="Leon" category="AMBIENCE#GENERAL" polarity="positive" from="0" to="4"/>
    <Opinion target="specials" category="FOOD#QUALITY" polarity="positive" from="95" to="103"/>
    <Opinion target="atmosphere" category="AMBIENCE#GENERAL" polarity="positive" from="123" to="133"/>
    <Opinion target="French bistro fare" category="FOOD#QUALITY" polarity="positive" from="70" to="88"/>
    </Opinions>
</sentence>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
sentences = soup.find_all("sentence")
result = []
for sent in sentences:
    element = []
    if sent.has_attr("id"):
        element.append(sent["id"])
    opinions = sent.find_all("opinion")
    for op in opinions:
        el = []
        if op.has_attr("category"):
            el.append(op["category"])
        if op.has_attr("polarity"):
            el.append(op["polarity"])
        if op.has_attr("target"):
            el.append(op["target"])
        element.append(el)
    result.append(tuple(element))
print(result)
```

Result

```
[('1126814:0', ['RESTAURANT#GENERAL', 'positive', 'Leon'], ['AMBIENCE#GENERAL', 'positive', 'Leon'], ['FOOD#QUALITY', 'positive', 'specials'], ['AMBIENCE#GENERAL', 'positive', 'atmosphere'], ['FOOD#QUALITY', 'positive', 'French bistro fare'])]
```

Please let me know if this is the format in which you wanted the answer